# how to Creating pdf file

Tags: xamarin.android

I used a library itextsharp .

I used the following code to create PDF File and print it , but the next error occurs, what code is missing ?.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Suppression State Error Can not resolve reference: System.Drawing, referenced by itextsharp. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for System.Drawing, or remove the reference to itextsharp. print_pdf

full code

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using System.IO;
using Android.Content;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace print_pdf
{
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
// Set our view from the "main" layout resource
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
var directory = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory, "pdf").ToString();
if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
{
Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
}

        var path = Path.Combine(directory, "myTestFile.pdf");

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }

        var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        document.Open();
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
        document.Close();
        writer.Close();
        fs.Close();

        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file), "application/pdf");
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the add `System.Drawing.dll` as references

Right click on `References` --> `Add Referencesc` --> `Assembly` --> `Browse...` --> `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` --> select `System.Drawing.dll`.

Comment: THANKS LEO ZHU  CODE ERROR NOW Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: 'No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/sdcard/pdf/myTestFile.pdf typ=application/pdf }'
And the process stops at this part (" StartActivity(intent);")

Comment: @maher2020 Please check on your phone/Emulator that PDF opening application (Any app having Mapped action with "android.intent.action.VIEW") is installed or not.You could use the Intent Chooser, like so:`Intent chooseIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File"); StartActivity(chooseIntent );`